# How to Compare Elements of two excel sheets and add New Counts and Elements to previous sheet using Python

Tags: python, excel, dataframe, counter

I have `two Excel sheets`. `Excel-1` looks like this

```
Name   Sample-A    Sample-B
A1        2           3
B1        3           4
```

`Excel-2` looks like-

```
Type               Solution
Sample-A               A1
Sample-A               B1
Sample-B               B1
Sample-B               A1
Sample-A               C1
Sample-A               A1
```

What I need to do is, get the count of each element `A1,B1` for each sample and add it to `Excel-1`. If there is a new element in `Excel-2` (in this case `C1`) add it to `Excel-1` as well. For this particular example the result should look like this-

```
Name   Sample-A    Sample-B
A1        4           4
B1        4           1
C1        1           0
```

I need to this whole thing using `Python`.

So far I used `dataframe.count_values()` to extract the `total counts` from `Excel-2`. I used `dataframe.iloc[]` to create `dataframe`  for each type `(sample A and Sample B)` from `Excel-1`. But I am not sure how to add these values or new element in `Excel-1.
**Sample code** is given below-

```
df1 = pd.read_excel(File Location)  #Reading Excel-1
Sample_A_df=df1[(df1['Type']=='Sample-A')]  #Creating dataframe for each type
Sample_B_df=df1[(df1['Type']=='Sample-B')]
CountA=Sample_A_df['Solution'].value_counts() #Getting counts for each element
CountB=Sample_B_df['Solution'].value_counts()
CountAdf=CountA.to_frame() #Converting the Count series to dataframe
CountBdf=CountB.to_frame()

df2 = pd.read_excel(File Location)
AfromPrev=df2.iloc[16:43,0:2]  #iloc is used as I need values from this range only
BfromPrev=df2.iloc[16:43,[0,2]]
AfromPrevList=AfromPrev['Sample-A'].tolist() 
BfromPrevList=BfromPrev['Sample-B'].tolist()
```

*P.S. I am basically creating a new worksheet as I believe I can not edit an excel sheet in Python, I need to create a new workbook. *

I have only started learning python for a very few months now and I am not sure what to do next, I can not figure out the proper logic to execute this task.

Comment: How is your desired result having the value of 1 for Sample-B & B1 combination ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your Excel-1 is pulled in as df1 and Excel-2 is pulled in as df2:

```
df3 = pd.crosstab(df2.Solution,df2.Type)
```

This will make d3 dataframe look like:

```
Index  Sample-A Sample-B
A1     2        1
B1     1        1
C1     1        0
```

Then you set the column Name as index for df1 (Excel-1) using

```
df1 = df1.set_index('Name')
```

Then you concat the two dataframes(the crosstabbed one and the Excel1) using sum()

```
df5 = pd.concat([df1,df3]).groupby(level=0).sum()
```

This will make your desired df look like:

```
Index   Sample-A    Sample-B
A1      4           4
B1      4           5
C1      1           0
```

Comment: Hey,
I have tried this but df5 shows the count not the total value. :/

Comment: @T0167 Can you clarify/elaborate a bit more on how the total value is different and in which field/column ?

Comment: @T0167 I am clearly seeing the results appropriate; it is the total value

Comment: `df5` and `df3` are showing same result except that in `df3` the counts are `integer`, while in `df5` the counts are `float`.

Comment: We are missing something here. I have exactly replicated the solution I have posted. 
If your dataframe (excels) are exactly like the one posted in the question, then there should not be any float coming into picture.
Also, can you review your desired dataframe output in the question.
I suspect the value of 1 for Sample-B & B1 combination in your desired df output in the question is misleading ?

Comment: I used `df.iloc()` to extract data for `excel-1` which should give a `dataframe` output. I have checked each step and got expected output except for `df5`. 

FYI There is a `Sample-C` in `excel 2`. And all the outputs give proper count for `Sample-C` also. However, `Sample-C` is not present in `excel-1`.
Does this have anything to do with the output I'm receiving?

I appreciate your help. I am looking into the matter and if I come up with any solution and find the error,i'll update you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181128/discussion-between-asimo-and-t0167).